# AI projectile targeting, firing a rocket/bullet/etc. so that it intercepts a target

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I know this has been asked before, and I have gotten it working mostly. I've used code I've found here and other places:

```
tx = target_pos.x - self.pos.x
ty = target_pos.y - self.pos.y
tvx = target_vel.x
tvy = target_vel.y

# Get quadratic equation components
a = tvx*tvx + tvy*tvy - self.max_speed * self.max_speed
b = 2 * (tvx * tx + tvy * ty)
c = tx*tx + ty*ty

# Solve quadratic
ts = self.quad(a, b, c); # See quad(), below

# Find smallest positive solution
desired_vel = None;
if (ts):
    t0 = ts[0]
    t1 = ts[1]
    t = min(t0, t1)
    if (t < 0):
        t = max(t0, t1)  
    if (t > 0):
        desired_vel = Vector2D(target_pos.x + target_vel.x*t,target_pos.y + target_vel.y*t) * self.max_speed
```

This works, except it only works when the shooter is placed in the bottom right of the screen (it's a top down game with one shooter and one moving target). With that setup, the shooter always hits, but if I move the shooter to the bottom middle of the screen, the shooter only fires projectiles correctly once the target is to the right of the shooter, otherwise it just fires straight ahead. Here are some screenshot links to illustrate the problem.

[Accurate (shooter can't be seen in bottom left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/283yk.png)

[Inaccurate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/283yk.png#1)

It can be seen that the vector of the projectile is fine, it just doesn't follow it, for some reason.

[Projectile vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIH1W.jpg)

Comment: I'm guessing that when the algorithm works, the shooter is at coordinates {0,0}.  In the last line of code, you are computing the target's position at time `t` and using that as the aiming vector. That only works if the shooter is at {0,0}.

Comment: I'd check your projectile movement code, perhaps it's clamping values inappropriately.

Comment: That would make sense, user3386109; after a few more runs, I've noticed that nothing fires correctly when the shooter is in the middle of the screen. However, the first line takes into account the current correct position of the shooter. Where could the problem be?

Comment: I'm assuming that `t` is a scalar representing time, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, t is time to impact.

Comment: So `target_pos.x + target_vel.x * t` is the target's x position at time `t`, not the target's x position _relative to the shooter_ at time t.

Comment: Fixed it!

`desired_vel = Vector2D( (target_pos.x + target_vel.x * t) - shooter.pos.x, (target_pos.y + target_vel.y*t) - shooter.pos.y ) * self.max_speed`

Thanks. Maths isn't my strong suit, and honestly, I didn't know what I just did. But it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Just needed to change the last line to take into account the shooter's position.

```
desired_vel = Vector2D( (target_pos.x + target_vel.x * t) - shooter.pos.x, (target_pos.y + target_vel.y*t) - shooter.pos.y ) * self.max_speed
```